# Changing app display name without changing bundle identifier on App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have changed the bundle display name of my app and submitted the app on appstore.
Will it change it's name in the Appstore or not?

If my first app name was "XYZ" and now I have changed the display name in info.plist to "ABC", if I search my app in the AppStore, I want to find it as "ABC".

I've only changed the bundle display name, so is it ok or should I make other changes as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the App Store title of your App in iTunes Connect.

The display name defined in your plist is the title, which occurs on your home screen below your App icon.